# Creating cost surface for least cost water transport analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I am working on a project to derive least cost pathways between sites by dug out canoe travel.

Has anyone worked on a similar project or found a function like the Tobler hiking function that can be used for water transportation?

I am hoping to use ArcGIS 10.1 but I would be open to shifting to GRASS if that increases my options or coding with python.

Comment: I am hoping to use ArcGIS 10.1 but I would be open to shifting to Grass if that increases my options or coding with python

Comment: I'm curious to how you plan on applying something like the Tobler function (since it is based on slope)? Is this flat water canoeing or whitewater?

Comment: it would be a combination between ocean/coastal and river canoeing, I am thinking that there could be a function that involves currents somehow, although I don't have current data

Comment: Interesting. I think it would be easiest to do the weighting of the rivers based on their class (and direction), and the ocean on a the current/exposure (or distance to the coast?) if you could get that information. I'm sorry though, I don't know of a function off the top of my head.